# Input parameters getting disabled while creating AWS SSM task with terrform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-ssm

I have created Maintenance window and task to start EC2 instance using terraform below is the code:

```
resource "aws_ssm_maintenance_window_task" "StopTask" {
count  = var.Enabled == "true" ? 1 : 0
max_concurrency  = "100%"
max_errors       = "100%"
name             = "StopJumpEc2"
priority         = 1
service_role_arn = aws_iam_role.EC2_start_stop.0.arn
task_arn         = "AWS-StopEC2Instance"
task_type        = "AUTOMATION"
window_id        = aws_ssm_maintenance_window.StopWindow.0.id

targets {
    key    = "WindowTargetIds"
    values = [
        aws_ssm_maintenance_window_target.WinOsPatches_StopServer_Target.0.id
    ]
}

task_invocation_parameters {
    automation_parameters {
        document_version = "$DEFAULT"

        parameter {                        // same result if you remove or add this :(
            name   = "AutomationAssumeRole"
            values = [
                "",
            ]
        }
        parameter {
            name   = "InstanceId"
            values = [
                "{{RESOURCE_ID}}",
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

}

While AWS console shows this task as :
[image]

This is ending with error below

> the supplied parameters for invoking the specified automation document are incorrect.

What can be issue ?

Comment: Did you mean to insert an ID when you wrote `{{RESOURCE_ID}}`?

Comment: No, this is to get instance ID from resource group attached in Targets